# Redux Reducer - How to update an object value without mutating the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability, reducers

My reducer looks like this:

```
  const players = (state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_PLAYERS_CARDS':
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          [action.player]: {
            name: state[action.player].name,
            score: state[action.player].score,
            cards: action.cards
          }
        })
       default:
         return state
    }
  }

  export default players
```

Basically, I just want to update the players cards but if I don't include the name and the score, then those get deleted in the new state.

Ideally I need to just do something like this: `state[action.player].cards = action.cards`  but one of the rules is to **never mutate the state**.

The method above will work, but that requires me to always know the data structure so if I add something else to it in the future, I would need to remember to come back to this reducer and add that back in so I don't lose it.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

**Edit:** Thanks to Vijay for the suggestion for multiple object assigns. I ended up getting it to work with this:

```
case 'UPDATE_PLAYERS_CARDS':
  const playerObject = Object.assign(state[action.player], { cards: action.cards });
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    [action.player]: playerObject
  });
```

How is that? Let me know if there are any improvements I can make.

Comment: might consider immutable.js and readup on react's native:  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html

Comment: Are you using babel? Do you have `stage-2` preset enabled?

Answer (score 6):

Multiple `Object.assign` methods look ugly.

You can do:

```
return { ...state.action.player, cards: action.cards }
```

Note: You'll need `stage-2` babel preset to use this.

Once the data structure to update becomes fairly complex, you can use [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) 's `setIn`, `updateIn` methods to do *deep updates* easily.

Comment: `Object.assign` is truly one ugly mf

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Object.assign might help:

```
const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
Object.assign(newState.action.player, { cards: action.cards });
```

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I edited my answer to reflect my new solution which stemmed from your answer. What do you think of that?